# Need to get Feature Title in method with BeforeTestRun attribute

Tags: c#, nunit, specflow, reportportal

Hooks.cs

```
[BeforeTestRun]
 public static void BeforeTestRun()
        {
            _ = new RpExtension("some feature title");
        }
```

RpExtension.cs

```
public class RpExtension
    {
        private string _featureTitle;

        public RpExtension(string featureTitle)
        {
            _featureTitle = featureTitle;
            ReportPortalAddin.BeforeRunStarted += ReportPortalAddin_OnBeforeRunStarted;
        }

        private void ReportPortalAddin_OnBeforeRunStarted(object sender, RunStartedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.StartLaunchRequest.Description = $"Feature: {_featureTitle}";
        }
    }
```

I know that we cant get FeatureContext in BeforeTestRun, but I want to set feature title in launch description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    [BeforeTestRun]
    public static void BeforeTestRun()
    {
       ReportPortalAddin.BeforeRunStarted += ReportPortalAddin_OnBeforeRunStarted;               
    }

    private static async void ReportPortalAddin_OnBeforeRunStarted(object sender, RunStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
              {
                 Wait.For(() => FeatureContext.Current != null
                                     && FeatureContext.Current.FeatureInfo != null
                                     && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(FeatureContext.Current.FeatureInfo.Title));

                 e.StartLaunchRequest.Description = FeatureContext.Current.FeatureInfo.Title;
              }
     }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).